# Problem using RenderAction() with the current action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, components, partial-views, renderaction

I'm building an ASP.Net MVC 2 application with a component architecture. There are two different types of components: *Elementary Components*, which have an associated controller action rendering a partial view, and *Layout Components*, which render all their child components (Elementary Components or again Layouts) in a certain layout.

Here is my generic **RenderComponent()** action method, which takes a component ID and renders the appropriate view:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult RenderComponent(int id)
{
    ComponentRepository repository = new ComponentRepository();
    Component component = repository.GetComponent(id);
    if (component.ControllerName != null && component.ViewName != null)
    {
        // render elementary component
        return PartialView("Elementary", component);
    }
    else 
    {
        // render layout
        return PartialView(component.Layout.ViewName, component);
    }
}
```

**Elementary.ascx** renders an elementary component:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyApp.Models.Component>" %>
<% Html.RenderAction(Model.ViewName, Model.ControllerName); %>
```

Currently the only existing layout is the **VerticalLayout.ascx**:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyApp.Models.Component>" %>
<% 
    foreach (var child in Model.ChildComponents()) {
%>
    <div class="layout-container">
    <% Html.RenderAction("RenderComponent", "Core", child.ID); %>
    </div>
<%
    }
%>
```

---

**The Problem:**

When I tried to render an example layout component with three associated elementary child components, the page wouldn't render. Some debugging revealed the following problem:

`RenderComponent(5)` renders the layout view.
For rendering the first child component in the layout, `Html.RenderAction("RenderComponent", "Core", 1)` is called in the view. Stepping further, I discovered that in effect `RenderComponent(5)` is called instead of `RenderComponent(1)`!!

This obviously results in an infinite loop of the layout view rendering itself.

---

Why is this happening? How can I fix it? Is my hierarchical component architecture incompatible with ASP.Net MVC? How would you build such a system in ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my bad... Of course it has to be `<% Html.RenderAction("RenderComponent", "Core", new { id = child.ID}); %>` in VerticalLayout.ascx.